# Is Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew are bad practice for windows phone or any other client platform?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone, async-await

I have WP 8.1 app that using web service a lot, and I want to keep it as much responsive as possible. From iOS dev expierense - there is one strict rule: "Do not do in UI thread any complex calculations! Doesnt matter how you will reach this: with blocks or with GCD".

Problem that not all API has async versions, e.g. JSON.NET, SQLite or any own complex algorithm in the app. I have read a lot of [articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) that are defining Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew as bad practice + [this](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/66).

So, is it good to write code like this? Will it cause some cpu overloading/battery drain/stability issues? If async wrappers are bad idea - what is the right way to make complex operations async(background thread)?

```
 protected async Task<T> GetDataAsync<T>(string uriString, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var uriToLoad = new Uri(uriString);
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response= await httpClient.GetAsync(uriToLoad, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            var dataString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // async wrapped call to sync API
            var result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(dataString), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Task.Run`/`Task.Factory.StartNew` is OK for CPU-bound operations. For IO-bound ones without "true" async API implementation, this is the only way to do something in background, because alternative is to do the same in UI thread. Don't be too categorical.

Comment: Take a look at the articles on [my async-await curation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx "async-await General"), specially [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx "Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stephen toub's article says that exposing asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods in a **library** is bad. That adds no value. If the developer wants, he can always call `Task.Run(()=> SomeSynchronousMethod());`. There is no need to expose it in a library. If it is an application, yes you can, because that is the only way you can off load the work.

Same applies to "Newtonsoft.Json". because it is a library.

> Is Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew a bad practice for windows phone
>   or any other client platform?

Yes and no.

If you have some heavy computation to do. Say image processing or something like that. You'll anyway have to do it; It needs some cpu cycles. No matter what thread you run, it will need some amount of cpu time. Which means that you must have to consume the cpu and of course battery.

> Is Task.Run or StartNew bad?

Not really when you have CPU bound work. That's what they are for.

If you need to get your work done, you need a Thread, it can't be UI thread(we need it to be responsive). So, nothing wrong in borrowing a ThreadPool thread using Task.Run or StartNew .

> When it is bad?

It is bad if you're using it when you can use naturally asynchronous API. Network I/O, File I/O etc are inherently asynchronous. [You don't need a thread to invoke truly asynchronous operation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Using threads for IO is just wasting a thread by sitting and doing nothing till the underlying device to completes the IO.

In short use Task.Run for CPU bound and naturally asynchronous API for IO bound operations.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you've misunderstood the article you've referred to (Stephen Toub's). That article is not discussing the using of `Task.Run()`, etc. in general. Rather, he is commenting on whether a *library* should wrap its fundamentally synchronous operations in tasks and expose that as part of the library's API.

From Toub's article:

> If a developer needs to achieve responsiveness or parallelism with synchronous APIs, they can simply wrap the invocation with a method like Task.Run

I.e. it's not bad to wrap a synchronous API with `Task.Run()` or similar, as long as that's the choice of the developer of the *client* code.

As far as what implications there are if you, as the developer of the client code, do this are, that depends entirely on the API.

First, it is definitely preferable to use for inherently asynchronous operations an API that already supports that. For example, network I/O. Any decent library providing high-level access to network protocols should provide some kind of asynchronous API, if not an `async`-compatible one.

But if you are stuck having to use a library that only has synchronous methods even for I/O or other kinds of asynchronous behaviors, you can in fact wrap those with an asynchronous call.

> Will it cause some cpu overloading/battery drain/stability issues?

In no case would I expect there to be a significant issues of those sorts. If the operation involves I/O, then the CPU isn't going to be busy while you're waiting for the data to actually arrive. For other tasks, offloading the work to a background thread involves a tiny amount of overhead; assuming there's really a need to keep the work out of the UI thread in the first place, then the work itself is so costly CPU-wise, the extra CPU utilization to manage the background task will be negligible.